Device is not charging (how to test ic)?
I have this USB-C rechargable vacuum cleaner. But 2 months after I replaced the battery for a bigger one (from 1500 to 3000 mah 18650) it is not charging anymore, it used to charge with the latter battery though.
I am so novice in this kind of pcb and even although it looks very simple, I guess the problem is in the IC it says: "5705", how should I check if it's shorted or something is burned?
In M- and M+ I dont know if my multimeter is out of calibration but i reckon it measured 0 ohm (shorted)?
Images:




volts connected to USB CHARGER:



Did you solder wires to the replacement battery (instead of spot welding them)? You might have shortened its lifespan considerably if you did.

Yes i 'm awared of that, but I doubt it should have something with the issue.

Q1: does the motor work? Q2: When charger is connected, is there the 5V on connector pins?

Q3: How do you know that it is not charging? Please provide voltage measurements (since you have a DMM) on each pin of the IC when Type-C  charging cable is plugged in.

have you verified the power supply fitness?

Ok, after deeper reading, do you mean that the device was working fine for 2 months after you replaced the cell, and only then it failed?

Yes, I said so. Besides, today i noticed something that "could" be the reason. The stock cell that it came with (low discharge cell) (drained about 3 ~ 4amp) measured at the motor start, the one i replaced, (high discharge cell) when i measured the engine it draws from 10 to 12 amps and then stays at 8 amp. Could it be the reason of a damaged IC? I know, i know the whole thing cost about 4 dollars but I 'm just trying to understand how things work and how things could get destroyed. If you guys can confirm that MIGHT be the reason, maybe i should have added a resistor (but dunno where). =)

You've been already asked, "Please provide voltage measurements (since you have a DMM) on each pin of the IC when Type-C charging cable is plugged in.". Each pin please. If you want to understand, get the data first.

Ok @Ale..chenski I measured all 6 pins while connected to the USB charger, volts result are in the new picture updated.

Yep, it looks like it will be a long run. In electronics, voltages are usually measured relative to known ground rail, GND is quite obvious in this design and pictures. People can then calculate differences on their own if needed. Again, please append your question with a table of voltage on every pin: PIN1 = ???V, PIN2 = ???V, etc.

My bad @Ale..chenski I did my best. Is it better?

Here is the most reasonable theory of what did happen.
As @nanash1 noted, the IC is likely a linear TP4057 IC. From this and PCB layout, Pin 3 is the IC output.
Now, the cell was replaced with a higher-discharge cell, which provides up to 8A current to a brushed motor. The motor is an inductor, and when the power switch is turned off, there should be enormous spikes of voltage, likely hundreds of volts. The IC likely has some protection against the spikes, but apparently not enough (and note, that C1 is omitted on the board), and after 2 month of device exploitation the IC finally broke down. This device will probably break down even if you didn't replace the cell, the design does not seem to have any snubber circuit to suppress the on-off voltage spikes, see this subject.

hundreds of volts? while running in my hand and holding the wires with my bare fingers I didnt feel anything.

@Panamanian, bare fingers are not an exact instrument to research 100-ns wide pulses. You might not feel much, but a semiconductor junction will be fried.

We can't look inside the IC, so we can't really know what goes wrong. Top of my head, several things might be happening:

Damage from soldering to battery or IC
IC noticed that over long-time average, charging takes longer than it should for the original battery, and assumes battery damage, shuts down
IC was not designed for larger battery with lower internal resistance and overloaded / overheated over time
original battery was chosen for larger internal resistance, delivered more power than it was designed to regularly handle, and grew metal whiskers and is now damaged. IC detected that damage and won't dangerously charge it.
IC is OK, but device was designed with smaller battery in mind, meaning that charging cycles were shorter and hence thermal constraints less severe. Over time, any critical component might have been damaged.
Damage completely unrelated to the battery / charging logic; after all, this very clearly is a low-cost consumer electronics design, so reliability might have been a trade-off with production price.

Either way, I don't really see any promising path forward to repair. You should probably carefully test your battery, and design a replacement charger/control board for the powers necessary.

It's almost certainly a TP4057. The pinout matches perfectly and the 57 marking also hints in that direction (57b* is more common though).

@nanash1 that doesn't change at all that we can't look inside!

I never said it does. But it makes some of your points very unlikely, specifically 2 and 3.

@nanash1 that's very true!
